# How can I stop Zoom from hijacking my screen?

Tags: zoom-meeting

Apologies if this question has been asked before,  I could not find an answer. And though I see this problem in Zoom, it might exist in other apps too.

when you join a zoom meeting that hasnt started, the app hijacks your screen. You cannot minimise it (there is no minimise button) or move it off the screen(in many apps, you can move them to bottom right and they vanish off screen, but Zoom doesn't), and it sits there covering my screen. If the meeting is 10 minutes late, I have that window covering my screen for 10 minutes, and it is very distracting.

This is what I mean:

[image]

Can I force this screen to be minimised?